# How to exit a promise from within a promise?

Tags: promise, break, raku

How do I exit a promise from within a promise? The perl6 docs do not provide an easy method. For example:

```
my $x = start {
    loop { # loop forever until "quit" is seen
        my $y = prompt("Say something: ");
        if $y ~~ / quit / { 
            # I want to exit the promise from here; 
            # "break" and "this.break" are not defined;
            # "return" does not break the promise;
            # I do NOT want an error exception when exiting a promise;
            # I want to return a value as the result of this promise;
        }
        else { say $y; }
    }
}
```

I do not want to be in the promise loop forever. `break()` and `this.break()` are not recognized, and `return` does not break the promise.

Comment: The title is misleading, you mean “exit from a `start` block”; as there are other ways to create a Promise. The simplest of which is to call `Promise.new()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`last` keyword](https://docs.perl6.org/syntax/last) to quit the loop.

The kept value of a `start` block is the value returned by its last statement.

So:

```
my $x = start {
    loop { # loop forever until "quit" is seen
        my $y = prompt("Say something: ");
        if $y ~~ / quit / {
            last 
        }
        else { say $y; }
    }
    42 # <-- The promise will be kept with value `42`
}
```